# play again not working

Tags: python, math

In my code for a maths quiz when i type N when it comes up with play again it plays again when it shouldnt. Here is my code:

```
def play_again():
    again= input("would you like to play again? y for yes and n for no")
    while again not in ['Y','y','N','n']:
        again = input("please enter 'Y' or 'N'")

    if again== 'y' or 'Y':
        do_the_quiz()
    else:
        print("cheers lad thanks for playing")
        exit()
```

can you spot something wrong in it that makes N or n play again when it shouldnt.

Comment: Try typing `'n' == 'y' or 'Y'` in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your if condition is wrong.
It can either be:

```
if again=='y' or again=='Y':
```

or

```
if again in ['Y', 'y']:
```

Answer (score 0):

`if again== 'y' or 'Y':` does not do what you think it does. `or` is a boolean operator, so the following is the same: `if (again == 'y') or ('Y')`. Because chars are alwayse treated as `True` in a boolean context your if branch will alwayse execute.